# clReleaseMemObject in OpenCL

Tags: opencl, gpgpu

When I create a buffer and later release the buffer by clReleaseMemObject function, there are always something strange, for example, if I set the size of the buffer as 128KB+8B, then an exception always occurs (frequently, but not each time, it always occurs after several normal executions), but if I set the size as 128KB or 256KB or some other size as integral power of 2, then clReleaseMemObject can always work well. I am not quite sure whether there is a constraint in the size of the buffer in OpenCL, anybody know any implications on this issue? Thanks!

Comment: *"then an exception always occurs"* - What *"exception"*? Does the program crash? Does it throw an actual C++ exception? Does it result in an OpenCL error code (and if yes, what's that error code)? Or are you using the C++ API and get an exception thrown as a result of an OpenCL error code (in this case again, what error code is it)? If it's that unfrequently it might be due to something more or less unrelated, like a heap corruption in the CPU code or whatever. Or maybe you're mapping it and writing over the bounds of 128KB+8B. Or maybe it's an alignment issue.

Comment: Anyway, a bit more information would be required to solve this issue, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

There are some constraints related to alignment of subbuffers but these should affect previous calls, not the one that releases mem object. Other is for instance CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE but valid implementation won't allow you to create buffers/images if these rules are not followed.

Your issue looks like related to some buffer overruns.